# Identify the type of circuit breaker

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker

I'm trying to identify this type of circuit breaker (i.e. so I can find replacements, etc.), and so far can't find any matches. Unfortunately, I didn't take any pictures of the panel, and can't do so for a while. There are no identification marks on the breakers that I can find, nor could I google anything useful.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Another breaker from the same box had a bit of a different side notch (nevermind the missing connectors, I gutted the breaker. Btw, there were were no identifying marks inside either):
[image]

I don't think the notch matters for my box, as the breakers face each other in the box, and there is absolutely nothing between them.

Comment: Do you remember if all the breakers in the box in question have the tan handles?

Comment: I don't *really* remember, but probably not. Both the single pole 20A did, but there is a "mystery" 2-pole with no writings, which I think is white, and the 2-pole 100a also is white I think.

Comment: Generally we need to know information about the *panel* not the breaker, because people use the wrong breaker all the time, so you can't go by that. (though in your case nothing else fits a CH).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Eaton CH

This is an (old) Eaton CH breaker -- the tan handle, hook-on-end mounting clips, and jaw system are quite similar to what you'd find on a current-production CH breaker, even.

Comment: Thank you! I could find those around, and they do look like what I need. There is no more notch on the front, but as I said, that doesn't seem functional.

Answer (score -7):

**Editor's Note:**

This is *dangerously* poor advice. You can't just "mix-n-match" breakers in a panel. You can *only* use breakers that are specifically certified for that panel. Failure to do so is not only a code violation but a likely fire starter that can not only destroy a house, but can kill people.

---

**Original Answer:**

The hook is absolutely functional, it is needed to attach the front of the breaker into place in the panel. I believe that you can also use Siemens, GE or square D homeline not square D QO, they are different type of connection.  If you can find the same brown switch Eatons that's the way to go but I believe all the 1s I listed use the same breaker body so any of them should work just double check em b4 u buy any.

Comment: This is _dangerously_ poor advice. You can't just "mix-n-match" breakers in a panel. You can _only_ use breakers that are specifically certified for that panel. Failure to do so is not only a code violation but a likely fire starter that can not only destroy a house, but kill people. This is why you're getting so many down votes. _Please_, for your own safety and that of others, do not repeat this "belief" to anyone else!

Comment: Note edited in following the suggestions in [this Meta question](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70).

Comment: Especially not with CH lol, as nothing else fits CH. The reason for the rule is that bus stabs are actually proprietary designs. Here you are thinking "they are standard like USB", no the exact opposite, each company was making theirs different to avoid patent infringement.  An alien bus clip won't grab the stab properly, will make bad connection, ovreheat and start a panel fire.  VERY nasty business, panel fires!